# Dynamically create action methods based on array in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methods, dynamic, controller, action

I have got a List and I want to dynamically create action methods based on the array. I am very new to mvc. Do we have a way that I can use the values of my list for my action method names.

For example: We have a list of Books Fiction, Science, Maths and I have a controller BookController. Then how to implement create dynamic action methods like

```
public Class BookController: Controller
{
public ActionResult Fiction(){}
public ActionResult Science(){}
public ActionResult Maths(){}
}
```

Comment: You should go to ASP.Net and learn from samples, like [MVC Music Store](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can dinamically create action methods on runtime, you should only use one method and iterate your list inside this method. Whats the reason of your code anyway maybe i can help further if i understand what you want to do.

Comment: I have a table which consists of the values based on which I am creating some links in my view. I want that in future if someone add a new value then the view should not break the code. The view is having common functionality.

Comment: Maybe you can render the table with an identifier so when you add a new value you can get it in the same action and you can identify the type of value

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will give it a try